# 40 seconds `fsck` of some drive at boot

Tags: linux-mint, fsck

On my Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon I just experienced very slow boot, which never happened before:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
40.890s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c5da2d40\x2d42ce\x2d4193\x2d9f21\x2d08ab6de8764d.service
```

I just woke up, turned on my laptop with Samsung NVMe 2TB drive, but the boot took ages, I went to look into some logs unsuccessfully, only the above showed some potential problem.

How can I now investigate why the drive `fsck` took so long? Is it logged somewhere? Thank you!

---

### `/run/initramfs/fsck.log`

```
Log of fsck -C -f -y -T -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Thu Mar  2 00:08:51 2023

e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nvme0n1p2: 1885079/122093568 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 179291521/488354304 blocks

Thu Mar  2 00:09:00 2023
----------------
```

What could explain the extreme slow boot then?

---

From comments:

As `root` I've executed:

```
# pv -Wptearb </dev/nvme0n1 >/dev/null
1.82TiB 0:15:59 [1.94GiB/s] [1.94GiB/s] [==============================>] 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
$ tail -1 /etc/fstab
UUID=c5da2d40-42ce-4193-9f21-08ab6de8764d /mnt/5tb ext4 nofail,nosuid,nodev,nouser,auto,rw,async,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=5TB 0 1
```

This external 5TB HDD I recently added as a *static* USB unit = not unplugging it.

---

```
# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep 'Check interval'
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

and

```
# LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep 'Maximum mount count'
Maximum mount count:      -1
```

so it should be as simple as changing the very last column in `fstab` to zero. Let's see then.